# Divider for vertical LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, divider

So I'm trying to put a divider between views in a LinearLayout using the XML `android:divider` attribute.  When I use a vertical LinearLayout, no divider shows up.  When I use a horizontal LinearLayout, the divider shows up and works fine.  Here is the drawable I'm using for the divider (`drawable/one.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="1dip" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

And here is my LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:divider="@drawable/one"
              android:dividerPadding="10dp"
              android:showDividers="middle">
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test1"
            />

<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test2"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it not possible to use the divider attribute with a vertical linear layout or am I missing something?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the vertical layout, in the drawable, I think you need to replace

```
  <size android:width="1dip" />
```

with

```
  <size android:height="1dip" />
```

Comment: Or rather, you need to have two drawables, one with the width set to 1dip, and one with the height set to 1dip

Comment: You saved me from killing myself ;)

Comment: Damn, that should have been obvious. Thanks for this.